# Why ' from. ' is a wrong syntax in Django?

Tags: python, django

[image: When I type it using jupyter notbook for django]

How to import views successfully without any syntax error? I have already tried adding `* , .`.

My code is :

```
from django.urls import url
  from  . import views
    urlpatterns = [
      path('', views.index, name='index'),
 ]
```

[image]

I want to run a simple poll app in Django.

Comment: Sounds like you've got some weird invisible characters in your code.

Comment: [Relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1373/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The invalid character is the extra space before the '.'

Try this:

`from . import views`